# Fatal Exception: main java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

I am working on my app I updated my android studio totally after that I am facing a problem related to my app. There is no error in it but a run time exception that I am unable to understand please guide me about it

```
01-03 11:12:53.283 10560-10560/? W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x9cc9cb20)
01-03 11:12:53.283 10560-10560/? D/AndroidRuntime: procName from cmdline: com.example.moin.fyp
01-03 11:12:53.283 10560-10560/? E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.example.moin.fyp
01-03 11:12:53.283 10560-10560/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10560 SIG: 9
01-03 11:12:53.283 10560-10560/? D/AndroidRuntime: file written successfully with content: com.example.moin.fyp StringBuffer : ;com.example.moin.fyp
01-03 11:12:53.283 10560-10560/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.example.moin.fyp, PID: 10560
                                                   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions
                                                       at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
                                                       at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1591)
                                                       at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1562)
                                                       at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:4794)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4389)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4325)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is my code of Java

```
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.widget.TableLayout;

import com.example.moin.fyp.Activities.Activities.Adapters.ViewPagerAdapter;
import com.example.moin.fyp.Activities.Activities.Fragments.Maps_Fragment;
import com.example.moin.fyp.R;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    TabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Cab Booking App");

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new     ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragemnt(new Maps_Fragment(),"Maps");
        adapter.addFragemnt(new Maps_Fragment(),"Maps");

        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

    }
}
```

here is XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!--android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.moin.fyp.Activities.Activities.MainActivity">-->

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode="scrollable">

        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: The relevant detail in the stacktrace is "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions"  meaning the code is trying to create a FirebaseOptions object and the definition of it is missing at runtime.

Comment: My Android studio Generates APK and install it to emulator but when application is executed it suddenly stops.